Application of KKT conditions to 4-dimensional problem
For a given vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^4$ we state the following problem
\begin{align*}
\max_{\lambda, b} \lambda y_4 + b_4 \text{ s.t. } y^Tb = 0, (\lambda -1)² \|y\|² \leq 0, \|y\|² = \|b\|²
\end{align*}
Now this problem is feasible. From the inequality it yields that $\lambda = 1$ and then we can use Gram-Schmidt to find $b$ and scale it to the right size.
I tried to solve this problem with KKT which yields
\begin{align}
\gamma_1 y_1 - 2b_1 \gamma_2 &= 0 \\
\gamma_1 y_2 - 2b_2 \gamma_2 &= 0 \\
\gamma_1 y_3 - 2b_3 \gamma_2 &= 0 \\
1 + \gamma_1 y_4 - 2b_4 \gamma_2 &= 0 \\
y_4 + 2(\lambda-1) \| y \|² \mu &= 0 \\
y^T b &= 0 \\
\| y\|² &= \| b\| ² \\
(\lambda - 1 ) ² \|y\|² &\leq 0 \\
\mu &\geq 0 \\
\mu (\lambda-1)²\|y\| &= 0 
\end{align}
My problem is that this system is now only solvable if $y_4=0$ or $y=0$. How can this be?
